# Jquery mobile datepicker localization bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, datepicker

There is a bug related with the jquery ui datepicker plugin. Localization files initializes on document ready:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$.datepicker.regional['tr'] = {
    closeText: 'kapat',
    prevText: '&#x3c;geri',
    nextText: 'ileri&#x3e',
    currentText: 'bugün',
    monthNames: ['OCAK', 'ŞUBAT', 'MART', 'NİSAN', 'MAYIS', 'HAZİRAN', 'TEMMUZ', 'AĞUSTOS', 'EYLÜL', 'EKİM', 'KASIM', 'ARALIK'],
    monthNamesShort: ['OCA', 'ŞUB', 'MAR', 'NİS', 'MAY', 'HAZ', 'TEM', 'AĞU', 'EYL', 'EKİ', 'KAS', 'ARA'],
    dayNames: ['PAZAR', 'PAZARTESİ', 'SALI', 'ÇARŞAMBA', 'PERŞEMBE', 'CUMA', 'CUMARTESİ'],
    dayNamesShort: ['PZ', 'PT', 'SA', 'ÇA', 'PE', 'CU', 'CT'],
    dayNamesMin: ['PZ', 'PT', 'SA', 'ÇA', 'PE', 'CU', 'CT'],
    weekHeader: 'HF',
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''
};
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['tr']);
```

});

However, while using jQuery mobile, my datepicker codes are called in pageshow events and pageshow is called before document ready, so `$.datepicker.regional` array is empty at this phase.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, document ready code should be replaced with both ready and pageshow events:

```
$(document).one('ready pageshow', function() {
    $.datepicker.regional['tr'] = {
        closeText: 'kapat',
        prevText: '&#x3c;geri',
        nextText: 'ileri&#x3e',
        currentText: 'bugün',
        monthNames: ['OCAK', 'ŞUBAT', 'MART', 'NİSAN', 'MAYIS', 'HAZİRAN', 'TEMMUZ', 'AĞUSTOS', 'EYLÜL', 'EKİM', 'KASIM', 'ARALIK'],
        monthNamesShort: ['OCA', 'ŞUB', 'MAR', 'NİS', 'MAY', 'HAZ', 'TEM', 'AĞU', 'EYL', 'EKİ', 'KAS', 'ARA'],
        dayNames: ['PAZAR', 'PAZARTESİ', 'SALI', 'ÇARŞAMBA', 'PERŞEMBE', 'CUMA', 'CUMARTESİ'],
        dayNamesShort: ['PZ', 'PT', 'SA', 'ÇA', 'PE', 'CU', 'CT'],
        dayNamesMin: ['PZ', 'PT', 'SA', 'ÇA', 'PE', 'CU', 'CT'],
        weekHeader: 'HF',
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['tr']);
});
```

Note that `$(document).one` should be used instead of on for performance issues.
Although [jquery is not officially supporting jqueryui datepicker plugin](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/datepicker/)  for mobile usage, many people should be using it and this case is very likely to be faced. So, they should better update localization files...